# Are USB graphics adapters standard devices?

Tags: usb, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi

There have been numerous different USB-to-VGA, USB-to-HDMI etc. adapters on the market for years. They present themselves as a video graphics adapter and then the operating system uses them like any other monitor. There's usually a small delay and maximum resolution and refresh rate is limited by USB transfer rates. (I'm not talking about USB-C to HDMI, for example, which are just mechanical adapters AFAIK.)

I have been unable to find information whether these devices are using "standard USB drivers". I put the last part in quotes because I'm not sure if this is the correct way to say it. What I mean is: does an operating system provide drivers for any or most USB-to-X graphics adapters? Or are the adapters using their own manufacturer-provided (or translation chipset vendor-provided) drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not. Instead, there’s only one chip maker: [DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink). Their proprietary technology powers *all* USB graphics adapters. They provide their own drivers, which do not ship with operating systems (except maybe Chrome OS).

Comment: There's at least one alternative but very obscure with likely <1% market share. I know this after trying to help someone at AU a couple of years ago. We ended up with no solution because unlike DisplayLink, this alternative chipset has no support for Linux.